# React - how to add boolean field on props when using map(), given that the field will be changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-hill-7klh3?file=/src/App.js

There are 3 items in my frontend.

data.json

```
{
  "items": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "title 1" },
    { "id": 2, "title": "title 2" },
    { "id": 3, "title": "title 3" }
  ]
}
```

When I click the arrow button for title 1, the arrow button for title 1 should be changed.

[image]

It seems like I need to add one more field in each item(`isExpanding` etc), but I cannot figure out where should I add this field

Comment: You will need to create a component use that for each item to be able to set the expanding state for each one, instead of one state for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a component `ListItem` for each entry in this list of data, and give it a piece of state to keep track of whether or not it's opened

```
// Overly simple example of said component... 

const ListItem = ({ id, title }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <li>
        {title} 
        <span>{isOpen ? <ExpandMoreIcon /> : <ExpandLessIcon /> }</span>
      </li>
    </>
  )
};
```

I wouldn't recommend adding another field to the data, since it concerns the state of the UI and not the data itself (separation of concerns).

Answer (score 0):

**checkout the below codesandbox link, I hope it works for you.**

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-river-1hmx1?file=/src/MyList.jsx